# Java how to update a Transient Column

Tags: java, spring, jpa, backend

I currently have a transient column in A Table. Let's say this column is human The column Refers to one of B Class(Hand)'s value which is something like humanHandWidth.
I am currently having trouble where i have the backend logic
Save to the table A initially(transient column gets entered as null) as I am not passing in the Hand object initially to the table A save -> Now, I make save to the table B - > now I want to grab the value of table b's humanHandWidth to the first table A which was initially null.
but here I am getting error because the column is transient. It is not allowing me to update. The reason why I am not turning off transient at the moment is because we don't want the table B to always get updated when we make update to table A. We want the table B's save to be final.

How do we make only updates to the table A's column value and nothing else happen?

Comment: Show the entities and mappings as it is hard to follow your description and the logic you are after. Transient just means it is invisible to serialization both ways, so it isn't clear what it has to do with Table b or how you are getting that value. TableA presumably has a reference to TableB, so presumably your class instances should as well, so a 'getHumanHandWidth()' method should just go to the referenced TableB instance and call 'getWidth()' - if it is mapped to a width property in B.

Comment: hey Chris, thanks to the quick response. When I create an entry in the hand table, the SequenceId is generated called handId, and the table A has a column called handId which has @Transient annotation, and in database its value  that we want to enter in table A is hand.handId.

Comment: Still not following - show your java classes and mappings. You cannot set a column in Table A without some mapping for it, so it is unclear what you want - it isn't read from that column either; that is the point of transient, it is invisible to your storage/serialization processes. It will never be there unless you set it each and every time a new instance (actual java object constructor) is called. I think you are confused and incorrect if you think that having a ClassA->ClassB reference and mapping means that updating ClassA and saving means ClassB data also is saved - you control it.